# How to Json In PHP 'iyas'

Tags: php

http://simsimi.com/getRealtimeReq?uuid=VbQqwsQ3qiCw1T04VrrFQzBBlkfZibg3YFkbWz6VquZ&lc=id&ft=1&reqText=Eh+jelek&status=W

How to get value from respSentence

Im using php lang ^_^

Comment: Very bad question please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `" {"status":200,"respSentence" 11 \`:"respSentence"}"` is not valid json.

Comment: Sorry ,i know that . But ,im using web stackoverlow from mobile. And im bad english ,i hope u can help me.

Comment: http://simsimi.com/getRealtimeReq?uuid=VbQqwsQ3qiCw1T04VrrFQzBBlkfZibg3YFkbWz6VquZ&lc=id&ft=1&reqText=Eh+jelek&status=W can help me to get value of respSentence?

Answer (score 0):

`" {"status":200,"respSentence" 11 \`:"respSentence"}"` is not valid json. Use some online sites to validate your json and try like this,

```
$json = '{"status":200,"respSentence" :"iyas"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true); 
echo $array ['respSentence'];
```

Comment: http://simsimi.com/getRealtimeReq?uuid=VbQqwsQ3qiCw1T04VrrFQzBBlkfZibg3YFkbWz6VquZ&lc=id&ft=1&reqText=Eh+jelek&status=W how to get value of respSentence?

Comment: `$json = file_get_contents('http://simsimi.com/getRealtimeReq?uuid=VbQqwsQ3qiCw1T04VrrFQzBBlkfZibg3YFkbWz6VquZ&lc=id&ft=1&reqText=Eh+jelek&status=W');
$array = json_decode($json, true); 
echo $array ['respSentence'];` - Try this.

Comment: Im using that ,and result : null

Comment: It is working from my local... Please check your configuration and running environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)** and **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** PHP functions

```
$url = "http://simsimi.com/........";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data, true);
echo $json ['respSentence'];
```

hope it helps